# Container hidden behind other container

Tags: html, css, css-position, containers

I am pretty sure this is a positioning issue, but unfortunately positioning is my weakness.

I have a container with a jquery image slideshow in it. The images in the slideshow have to be `{position: absolute;}` or else they will just display one after the other down the page.

Unfortuntely, the containers that come after the slideshow container are displaying behind the slideshow container, not underneath it. I think this is because of the absolute positioning of the slideshow images, but I don't know how to rectify it.

```css
    @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    #main {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #slideshow {
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
    }
    #slideshow IMG {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 8;
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
    #slideshow IMG.active {
      z-index: 10;
      opacity: 1.0;
    }
    #slideshow IMG.last-active {
      z-index: 9;
    }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*** 
        Simple jQuery Slideshow Script
        Released by Jon Raasch (jonraasch.com) under FreeBSD license: free to use or modify, not responsible for anything, etc.  Please link out to me if you like it :)
        ***/

    function slideSwitch() {
      var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

      if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

      // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
      var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

      // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

      // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
      // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
      // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


      $active.addClass('last-active');

      $next.css({
          opacity: 0.0
        })
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({
          opacity: 1.0
        }, 500, function() {
          $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
    }

    $(function() {
      setInterval("slideSwitch()", 3000);
    });
  </script>

  <link href="../../Assignment5-Portfolio/HTML/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main">


    <div id="slideshow">
      <img src="../Images/bike.png" width="100%" height="auto" class="active" />
      <img src="../Images/fish.png" width="100%" height="auto" />
      <img src="../Images/stairs.png" width="100%" height="auto" />
      <img src="../Images/gage.png" width="100%" height="auto" />
    </div>

    <div id="aboutme">About me</div>

    <div id="videography">Video
      <div id="text">text goes here</div>
      <div id="video">video goes here</div>
    </div>

    <div id="photography">
      <div id="photos">photos go here</div>
      <div id="photography"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

So, `#slideshow` is the container in question. The images in it are blocking the containers below it. I want the images to stretch across the whole width of the screen.

As I said, I'm fairly certain it's a positioning problem, but I feel like I could also be missing something important from the `#slideshow` container, but I can't find what it is.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: just a suggestion.. You should write your script at the end of the page instead in the head.Page will load faster!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put a wrapper div around the entire slideshow and give it `position:relative;` That way it will contain the slideshow and create the spacing you need.

If you will consider a bit more javascript you could add this tidbit of code

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 var objHeight = 0;
 $.each($('#slideshow').children(), function(){
        objHeight = $(this).height();
 });
 $('#slideshow').height(objHeight);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f4e55bcx/2/)

Comment: this is mostly correct, but based on the markup the slideshow div will suffice as the wrapper. I will upvote because you're not wrong and this would work, but using the slideshow div and adding a height to it is sufficient.

Comment: True, I should have inspected the OP's code more closely to pick that out. It would save some additional markup if the slideshow div is positioned relatively with a height assigned to it as you mentioned. Regardless, this is the method used to bring an absolutely positioned item back into the flow of the page so to speak.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about adding a height to the slideshow container, but I don't know what the height will be. The images scale to the width of the page, so what height do I put?

Comment: if you are uncertain about adding a height, try the above and just put a wrapper around the slideshow with the position relative. It will adopt the height of its inner elements.

Comment: Ok, so I added `<div id="wrapper">` around the slideshow container and set it to `position:relative;` but it still has a height of 0. Even the slideshow container itself has a height of 0? How can I set a height when the height will depend on the width of the window?

Comment: Thanks so much! We've made progress, but unfortunately it's not quite right. I added the javascript above and now both the wrapper and the slideshow container have a height, and the other containers are showing correctly beneath it, but the height is wrong. It's far too big. Lots of white space below the images before the other containers.

Comment: I've changed the javascript which had one small error in it. It should hopefully work now.

Answer (score 2):

the absolute and also relative positioned elements should have certain height and width (however block elements have the width:100% initially). Otherwise next elements will overlap with them. So if you have certain height for your images e.g. 400px then:

```
#slideshow {
position:relative;
width:auto;
height:400px;
}
```

Comment: `width: auto;` isn't 100% necessary, but if you do a width I would recommend a 100% width.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about adding a height to the slideshow container, but I don't know what the height will be. The images scale to the width of the page, so what height do I put?

Comment: As a jquery hack, you can get the height of images after window.load and set the height of container to the maximum height of images.